# CodenameOne Bluetooth Low-energy devices for Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, codenameone

I have downloaded the CN1Bluetooth Bluetooth LE library and started my scan but I couldn't see any Bluetooth devices. After reading I realised that this CN1 lib was for Bluetooth LE devices and I only have standard Bluetooth devices.

Does anyone have recommendations for Bluetooth LE devices (particularly barcode scanners) for Android?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really familiar with devices in this field. Notice LE == 4.0 so BT 4.0 should work